# Clicking day cells in Month View with JS

Tags: fullcalendar

I am writing some unit tests to handle clicking on a cell and I'm encountering this issue where manually clicking on a cell (or date) will trigger the clickHandler; however firing javascript click events does nothing. Here's an example video where I am firing a click event on the fullcalendar-demo-page https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo  https://share.getcloudapp.com/YEuopWQx

I've tried firing mousedowns and other pointer events. I would expect the events to bubble up to the top and fullcalendar to eventually handle them.

Comment: Where's your code, please? We can't fix any problems without seeing your implementation. A grainy video isn't sufficient for that. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more guidance. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson The reproduceable steps include 1. navigate to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting-demo 2. click on a cell 3. trigger a click with `$0.click()`.

Comment: you're assuming that's how fullCalendar makes its dateClick event work, but it ain't necessarily so. You'd have to check the source code to find out precisely how they do it.

Comment: But anyway, why do you want to simulate a click on a date? Maybe there's another way to achieve your overall aim, if you tell us what the purpose is.